# how to auto answer and incoming call given i have detected that the phone is ringing via my app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

```java
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        showText(context, "Call started da");
    } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        showText(context, "Call ended da");
    } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        showText(context, "Call ringing da");
    }
}

void showText(Context context, String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

This is my code. What should I add in the last else if so that my app will automatically attend the calls?

I viewed other StackOverflow pages regarding this but couldn't get a clear view. Kindly help me out with this.

I also saw that we can simulate a headphone button being pressed which inturn attends the call? How far is that true? Can that be used?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Auto answering is impossible.  Android framework doesn't allow it.  It is only avaible, when you can build your own android frame with modifying IntentManger.  such as ASOP.